# UPDATE 'tableA JOIN tableB' works for 1st SET (condition) only

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, set

I am trying to UPDATE a table after a JOIN with a second table. The UPDATE only works for the 1st `SET`.

Here is the code:

```
update Table_A 
join Table_B on Table_A.date  = Table_B.date
  set Table_A.columnA = case 
              when  Table_A.date = Table_B.date then Table_B.columnA
              else  Table_A.columnA
              end,
      Table_A.columnB = case
              when Table_A.field = 'aaa' then Table_A.columnA * 5
              when Table_A.field = 'bbb' then Table_A.columnA * 10
              else Table_A.columnB
              end,
      Table_A.columnC = '1000'
;
```

I run this on mySQL and when I return the results from the table it seems that the `UPDATE` works only for the first `SET`. In this case it is the 'columnA'.

I run this script again and I can see the results updated in 'columnB'.

I run it again and I have the results updated in 'columnC' too.

So, I have to run the script three times for every condition (3 in total) in the `SET`.

**UPD:** *I believe the problem is that the fields that get updated are being used for the next `SET`. 'columnA' gets updated in the first `SET` and then 'columnB' uses 'columnA'. But the script is not using the updated 'columnA' but the old one which is NULL.*

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Can you provide sample data and what you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Of course the `update` is using the "old" value for the columns.  That is how `updates` work, regardless of database.  The "old" values are on the right; the "new" values are on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three different updates is the only solution I can think of.

**Update no1:**

```
update Table_A 
join Table_B on Table_A.date  = Table_B.date
  set Table_A.columnA = Table_B.columnA;
```

**Update no2 :**

```
   update Table_A 
    join Table_B on Table_A.date  = Table_B.date
      set Table_A.columnB = case
                  when Table_A.field = 'aaa' then Table_A.columnA * 5
                  when Table_A.field = 'bbb' then Table_A.columnA * 10
                  else Table_A.columnB
                  end;
```

**Update no3:**

```
update Table_A 
join Table_B on Table_A.date  = Table_B.date
      Table_A.columnC = '1000'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first case is made redundant by your JOIN

```
UPDATE Table_A a 
  JOIN Table_B b
    ON b.date = a.date
   SET a.columnA = b.columnA,
       a.columnB = CASE
          WHEN a.field = 'aaa' THEN b.columnA * 5
          WHEN a.field = 'bbb' THEN b.columnA * 10
          ELSE a.columnB
       END,
       a.columnC = '1000'
```

looks like the logic you want.

You are correct that the old value of columnA will persist until the query is finished.

It appears that the denormalised nature of your table data is causing this to be a problem.

Unless this is a one-off patch, I would be concerned that your data structure will continue to give you grief.

Comment: I split the UPDATE into 3 and it works but I want to make it work in the best way. I guess I have to abandon the idea of the UPDATE, JOIN, SET thing or just deal with 3 UPDATES.

Comment: OK, that seems entirely reasonable, as long as there are no performance issues. I'd pop the 3 updates in a transaction though just to be safe too.